# D3.js add label to bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I add label to a bar chart? The bar chart extends along the x-axis and I want to append the labels along the y-axis.

I read some examples and they use an external .tsv or .csv file. Can I store them in an array instead? My code is below :

```
var data = [7, 8, 15, 16];
var label = ["as","bs","cs","ds"];

var width = 420,
  barHeight = 20;
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
  .range([0, width]);
var chart = d3.select(".chart")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);
var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });
bar.append("rect")
  .attr("width", x)
  .attr("height", barHeight - 1);
bar.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) - 3; })
  .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of your label by the index like this :

```
 bar.append("text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) - 3; })
          .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d, i) { return label[i]; });
```